# der Mann, dative form

Tags: grammatical-case, dative

The noun changes on dative form, should be added an **s** or **es**. Isn't that the rule?

Considering that I'll say **der Mann** becomes **dem Mannes** but the book I'm reading says it becomes **dem Mann**. Why?

Comment: *Why* what? Why does the book say that the dative of *Mann* is *Mann*? The answer is trivial: because it is.

Answer (score 2):

### No, it is not the rule that a noun ends on *-s* or *-es* being *dative*.

Those are *genitive* endings.

Dative nouns have either no ending in singular as your book says, or the archaic *-e* for masculine and neuter nouns.

In plural, there are several dative endings (e.g., *-en*, *-ern*).

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mann#German#Declension) the "**dative**-form" is **Mann** or *Manne* (*outdated*).

> **Wem** gehört das Auto? **Dem** **Mann** (meiner Frau).

The **s** or **es** is added in the "*genitive*-form":

> Das Auto *des* Mann**es**.

Comment: "... change to the noun itself occurs in the dative case if the noun is masculine, or in the genitive case if the noun is masculine or neuter." from the book (page 11) Basic German premium 2nd edition by Jolene Wochenske

Comment: @KcFnMi: True in most cases, but there are a few cases where masculine nouns change in the accusative: *Ich sehe einen Kunden.* Not to mention adjectival nouns which follow a different system. Your book probably does cover these exceptions eventually, but I can see why the author(s) wouldn't want to burden beginners with them at the start.

Comment: @KcFnMi, this seems to be a misleading formulation in the book. The **s** endings mark the genitive, not the dative. The preview of the book that I found included page 11 but not page 12, so I cannot say whether it gets clearer if one continues reading.